# Not understanding some (basic) Matlab commands to plot

Tags: matlab, plot

```
 plot([0 u(1,1)], [0 u(2,1)]);
 plot([0 u(1,2)], [0 u(2,2)]);
```

These commands do what I want. However, why are the zeros in front.

The effect of these commands is the second plot on the [page](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Exercise:PCA_in_2D):
[image]

Comment: I would recommend appending an `axis equal;`. This way you can verify that your PCA yields orthogonal vectors, as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0s are used to denote plotting boundaries; since Matlab need to have starting and ending values for both x and y.

For instance, in this statement:

```
plot([0 u(1,1)], [0 u(2,1)]);
```

the 2 terms in the first square brackets represent the range of x-values to plot, i.e. from 0 to u(1,1), while those in the 2nd square bracket represent the y-values. It basically plots a line going from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2), with x1 and y1 being (0,0), x2 being u(1,1) and y2 being u(2,1).

From the code you were given, u looks like this: (I'm not showing you the whole solution since this is homework :)

```
u =

   -0.7055   -0.7087
   -0.7087    0.7055
```

Therefore, the line corresponding to the line above will have x-values form 0 to u(1,1) = -0.7055 and y-values going from 0 to u(2,1) = -0.7087. The same applies for the 2nd call to plot.

Here is a figure obtained with the data; I plotted both curves with different colors so you can see the difference: (I used @knedlsepp's suggestion to use `axis equal` to see that both lines are orthogonal.

[image]

Hope that helps get you started. Good luck!

Comment: if the first two terms plot([0 u(1,1)], [0 u(2,1)]) represent ranges for x and y values, respectively, why doesn't  plot(0: u(1,1), 0 :u(2,1)) work?

Comment: Because u(1,1) is negative and writing 0:something negative in Matlab results in an empty array. You can try 'plot(0:-0.01:u(1,1), 0:-0.01:u(2,1))' and it will work.Notice the increment value -0.01 that is negative, telling Matlab to look in the negative direction.